# Template parameter extraction and modification

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I wrote the following class to extract the template parameters of a `Base` class and append to it the template parameters of a `Derived` class at compile time :

```
template <typename...> struct derived_type_traits;

// specialization for the case when Base is not a template
template <typename Base> struct derived_type_traits<Base> {
    template <template<typename...> class Derived, typename... DerivedArgs>
    using type = Derived<DerivedArgs...>;
};

// specialization for the case when Base is a template
template <template <typename...> class Base, typename... BaseArgs> struct derived_type_traits<Base<BaseArgs...>> {
    template <template<typename...> class Derived, typename... DerivedArgs>
    using type = Derived<DerivedArgs..., BaseArgs...>;
};
```

I use it as part of a factory building blocks.
With this traits class, I can construct a `Derived` from a set of template parameters and a `Base` class :

```
namespace A {
    class Base {};
    template <typename T>
    class Derived : public Base {};
    auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base>::type<Derived, int>();
}

namespace B {
    class Base {};
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    class Derived : public Base {};
    auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base>::type<Derived, int, double, std::string>();    
}

namespace C {
    template <typename T>
    class Base {};
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T>
    class Derived : public Base<T> {};
    auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base<int>>::type<Derived, int, double, std::string>();  
}
```

However, it does not work for the following cases :

```
namespace D {
    template <typename T>
    class Base {};
    template <typename T1, typename T2, template <typename,typename> class T3, typename T>
    class Derived : public Base<T> {};
    template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Foo {};
    auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base<int>>::type<Derived, int, double, Foo>();
}

namespace E {
    template <typename U1, template <typename,typename> class U2>
    class Base {};
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename U1, template<typename,typename> class U2>
    class Derived : public Base<U1,U2> {};
    template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Foo {};
    auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base<int, Foo>>::type<Derived, int, double, std::string>();
}
```

The test code is [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51a5ca220d8aa110).

I know that this is related to the fact that a variadic template can not match a mix of types and template types.

Is there a solution or am I going the wrong way about it ? I can use up to C++14 (no C++17).

Comment: You can't treat template-template and non-type parameters the same way as class parameter. You can wrap the TT to a normal class, something like `template<template<class...> TT> ttwrapper { template<class... Ts> using tt = TT<Ts...>; };` Also, TT with fixed length will cause problems in many cases, I'd suggest use variadic version consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you just know (and as explained by liliscent) template-template ad template-type parameter are different things, so you can't pass a template-template where is expected a template-type parameter. And vice versa.

I don't know what do you, exactly, want to do with your `derived_type_traits` but the best I can imagine, to solve this problem, is wrap template-template types in a struct and pass they as a typenames.

By example... if you define a "template template wrapper" `ttw` as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class>
struct ttw  // template template wrapper
 { };
```

you can modify you `D` case as follows

```
namespace D
 {
   template <typename T>
   class Base
    { };

   // now T3 is a typename !
   template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T>
   class Derived : public Base<T>
    { };

   template <typename T1, typename T2>
   struct Foo
    { };

   auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base<int>>::type<
      Derived, int, double, ttw<Foo>>();
   // ----------------------^^^^^^^^   and here Foo is wrapped
}
```

For case `E`, the best I can imagine is

```
namespace E
 {
   // now U2 is a typename !
   template <typename U1, typename U2>
   class Base
    { };

   template <typename T1>
   struct Foo
    { };

   // U2 is a typename also here
   template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename U1, typename U2>
   class Derived : public Base<U1, U2>
    { };

   //  and Foo is wrapped again -------------------------VVVVVVVV        
   auto ptr = new typename derived_type_traits<Base<int, ttw<Foo>>>::type<
      Derived, int, double, std::string>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are meta meta programming, and C++ does not really support that.  It is also a questionable plan,  sort of like 3 star programming.

If you want to meta meta program, you'll have to restrict your meta programming to be more uniform.  Turn everything into types.

Use `std::integral_constant` types to pass around values (even works on function pointers!).  Use

```
template<template<class...>class Z>struct ztemplate
```

to pass around templates.

Alternatively (or in addition) move to value based metaprogramming.  Pass types as `template<class>struct tag_t` values, templates are replaced with objects or functions that map from tags to tag, etc.

Both of these approaches permit easier and simpler recursively meta programming to a higher degree.

Doing this in raw C++ TMP runs into that problem, together with the fact that there are a bunch of annoying rules that end up tripping you up later (like passing packs to 1 argument templates) and mediocre compiler support.

Finally, note that in your concrete case:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename U1, template<typename,typename> class U2>
class Derived : public Base<U1,U2> {};
```

is way more awkward than:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, class Base>
class Derived : public Base {};
auto ptr = new Derived< int, double, std::string, Base<int, Foo>>();
```

Comment: *Both of these approaches permit easier...* --> I doubt your `ztemplate` wrapper really can do arbitrary high order metaprogramming. To achieve high order metaprogramming with only type computation, I would use `struct` without template to represent *every* meta construct, then an inner template `struct apply` to do computation.

Comment: @liliscent the inner template can be there, or it can be done outside with a helper.  Same difference.